Set UnsafeMutablePointer pointee from a different actor
UnsafeMutablePointer is not Sendable anymore and in Xcode 16 Beta using the build setting 'Strict Concurrency Checking', setting the pointee of the pointer from another actor (rightfully?) gives a warning.
Setting:

Problem:
Below code gives the warning Capture of 'shouldStopPointer' with non-sendable type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>' in a @Sendable closure; this is an error in the Swift 6 language mode. Generic struct 'UnsafeMutablePointer' does not conform to the 'Sendable' protocol (Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer)
How can I set the pointee in the correct actor, or otherwise prevent this warning?
Screenshot:

Code:
import SwiftUI import Photos

actor DifferentActor {
    func requestMetaData(progressHandler: @escaping PHAssetImageProgressHandler) async -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
        options.progressHandler = progressHandler
        
        let someAsset = PHAsset()
        
        let orientation = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: someAsset, options: options) { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, status in
                continuation.resume(returning: orientation)
            }
        }
        return orientation
    } }

@MainActor struct ContentView: View {
    let differentActor = DifferentActor()
    
    @State var photoMetadata: String?
    
    @State var progress: Double = 0.0
    
    @State var shouldStopGettingMetadata: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Button("Get metadata") {
                Task {
                    await downloadMetaData()
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Progress: ")
                ProgressView(value: progress)
            }
            
            Button("Cancel get metadata") {
                shouldStopGettingMetadata = true
            }
            
            Text("Orientation: \(photoMetadata ?? "Not yet loaded")")
            
        }
    }
    
    private func downloadMetaData() async {
        let orientation = await differentActor.requestMetaData { @Sendable progress, error, shouldStopPointer, info in
            
            Task { @MainActor in
                self.progress = progress
                
                if self.shouldStopGettingMetadata {
                    shouldStopPointer.pointee = true
                }
            }
        }
        self.photoMetadata = "\(orientation)"
    }
     }

#Preview {
    ContentView() }

If I make everything async, I get a different error:
Cannot pass function of type '@Sendable (Double, (any Error)?, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>, [AnyHashable : Any]?) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Screenshot:

Code:
private func downloadMetaData() async {
    let orientation = await differentActor.requestMetaData { @Sendable progress, error, shouldStopPointer, info in
        
        await self.progress = progress
        
        let shouldStop = self.shouldStopGettingMetadata
        
        if shouldStop {
            shouldStopPointer.pointee = true
        }
    }
    self.photoMetadata = "\(orientation)"
}


Watch Meet async/await all completion handlers should be converted. Once you start with async/await those are history. Instead of capturing return to the parent actor to make changes.

@loremipsum thanks for your help, but how? I can make requestMetaData async of course (just did), but I'd still have to deal with PHAssetImageProgressHandler. How does your suggestion work for PHAssetImageProgressHandler? I have no idea.

@loremipsum in this case you appear to have misunderstood the problem. The PHAssetImageProgressHandler provides a stop pointer, and Apple haven't provided a modern API for this, so there's no way around it except retroactive conformance to Sendable, until Apple choose to provide some new APIs.

@ClausJørgensen I haven't misunderstood, there is no need for the stop pointer to leave the hander/actor. you can just use task cancellation and fully convert to async/await

I'm going to leave this answer up because it introduces some useful tools, but @loremipsum's answer is better and gets Swift concurrency better than this answer.

Your problem isn't directly the other actor. It's that you've put the modification of the pointer inside a Task, and thus potentially on another thread, executed after this function returns. There is no way to make that safe. This isn't a Swift 6 thing or even a Swift thing. This would be unsafe in ObjC using GCD. Writing to a boolean like is done here is definitely an atomic operation, but it requires the Apple code to be very careful about how it reads the boolean. Apple probably is very careful about this given how they explicitly say it's ok to move this to the main queue, but... It's really not clear that what you've written here would even work reliably. Out-variables like this are generally expected to be written before the function returns.
Anyway, the compiler is right. This code is not safe. So how to make it safe?
First, it's a lot easier if you split your view and model logic. So instead of having all your state in View @State properties, move it to a model that is going to be more flexible.
@MainActor struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
    ...

And the "normal" part of your model is normal.
@Observable @MainActor final class Model {
    let differentActor = DifferentActor()

    var photoMetadata: String?
    var progress: Double = 0.0
    ...
}

Now to the fun part. You need a shouldStopGettingMetadata that is safe to read from any thread because PHAssetImageProgressHandler can be run on any thread. So add this property to Model:
import os

...

private nonisolated let shouldStopGettingMetadata = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: false)

You now have a variable that can be modified and read safely on any thread. So you can set it in a stop method:
func stop() {
    shouldStopGettingMetadata.withLock { $0 = true }
}

And you just need a tweak to downloadMetaData to update "stop" before returning:
func downloadMetaData() async {
    let orientation = await differentActor.requestMetaData { @Sendable progress, error, shouldStopPointer, info in

        // Update progress on MainActor
        Task { @MainActor in
            self.progress = progress
        }

        // But this is done synchronously
        if self.shouldStopGettingMetadata.withLock({ $0 }) {
            shouldStopPointer.pointee = true
        }
    }
    self.photoMetadata = "\(orientation)"
}

OSAllocatedUnfairLock (which will soon be available as Mutex) is a very important tool for bridging synchronous and asynchronous code, and particularly "messy asynchronous" like in this case. It is well worth adding to everyone's toolkit. I find I actually use it more than actor.
OSAllocatedUnfairLock requires iOS 16. If you need to go back earlier, you can use this backport of Mutex.

The full code:
import SwiftUI 
import Photos
import os

actor DifferentActor {
    func requestMetaData(progressHandler: @escaping PHAssetImageProgressHandler) async -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.deliveryMode = .opportunistic
        options.progressHandler = progressHandler

        let someAsset = PHAsset()

        let orientation = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: someAsset, options: options) { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, status in
                continuation.resume(returning: orientation)
            }
        }
        return orientation
    }
}

@Observable @MainActor final class Model {
    let differentActor = DifferentActor()

    var photoMetadata: String?
    var progress: Double = 0.0
    private nonisolated let shouldStopGettingMetadata = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: false)

    func stop() {
        shouldStopGettingMetadata.withLock { $0 = true }
    }

    func downloadMetaData() async {
        let orientation = await differentActor.requestMetaData { @Sendable progress, error, shouldStopPointer, info in
            Task { @MainActor in
                self.progress = progress
            }

            if self.shouldStopGettingMetadata.withLock({ $0 }) {
                shouldStopPointer.pointee = true
            }
        }
        self.photoMetadata = "\(orientation)"
    }
}

@MainActor struct ContentView: View {
    @State var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {

            Button("Get metadata") {
                Task {
                    await model.downloadMetaData()
                }
            }

            HStack {
                Text("Progress: ")
                ProgressView(value: model.progress)
            }

            Button("Cancel get metadata") {
                model.stop()
            }

            Text("Orientation: \(model.photoMetadata ?? "Not yet loaded")")
        }
    }

}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Rob maybe fair to mention your solution only works in iOS 16+ (because of OSAllocatedUnfairLock). So if you need to support iOS 15 (or even lower!) you might need a different solution.

Great point. I added a link to a well-vetted backport.

@RobNapier
"> and thus potentially on another thread, executed after this function returns. There is no way to make that safe." -> Absolutely, I am aware this was unsafe to begin with, and when I checked, the closure indeed executed on a different thread.
"> It's really not clear that what you've written here would even work reliably." -> Yes aware of it, but I needed a starting point towards the correct solution.
"> private nonisolated let shouldStopGettingMetadata = OSAllocatedUnfairLock(initialState: false)" -> Awesome. Thanks for the code samples. I'm gonna experiment with it.

You need to conform your pointer to @unchecked Sendable, which also works for older iOS versions unlike the other solutions presented here.
extension UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>: @unchecked Sendable {}

or in Xcode 16:
extension UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>: @unchecked @retroactive Sendable {}

See https://forums.swift.org/t/unsafepointer-sendable-should-be-revoked/51926 and https://github.com/swiftlang/swift/pull/39218

Thanks, but is it safe to do so?

@Arjan of course not, and that's the whole point isn't it. But since Apple isn't providing any other APIs, your only choice is to do a unsafe operation. The difference is the compiler forces you to acknowledge that you're doing a unsafe operation now.

Ah. I expected there was a safe, correct way of doing it, one I didn't know about.

This is a very dangerous conformance that impacts the whole system, not just this one usage. I would strongly advise against adding this. Making this code safe is not that difficult.

You can look at my solution, let me know what you think

@RobNapier sure because in this case it's a general type. Would been better had it been more specialised, but imo. it's a valid stopgap for existing code. Again, I think Apple should provide better APIs than asking people to wrap their APIs with Mutex and whats not.
